# JVM behaviour when OS runs out of memory

Tags: jvm

I am wondering what's the JVM behaviour for the following situation:

- JVM minimum heap size = 500MB
- JVM maximum heap size = 2GB
- OS has 1GB memory

After the JVM started and the program runs for a period of time, it uses more than 1GB memory. I wonder if OOM will happen immediately or it will try to GC first!

Comment: A JVM will always try GC before throwing an OOME, that’s mandated by the specification. If that doesn’t free enough memory to serve the pending allocation, you’ll get an OOME.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much swap space you have.

If you don't have enough free swap, the JVM won't start as it can't allocate enough virtual memory.

If you have enough free swap your program could start and run. However once a JVM starts swapping its heap the GC times rise dramatically.  The GC assumes it can access the heap somewhat randomly.

If your heap can't fit in main memory, the program, and possibly the machine becomes unusable. In my experience, on Windows, a reboot is needed at this point. On Linux, I usually find I can kill the process.

In short, you might be able to start the JVM, but it's a bad idea.